# ДЕСТРУКТУРИЗАЦИЯ В ЦИКЛАХ (автопроверки)

Tags: javascript

[image: Первый способ]

[image: Второй способ]

Первый способ:

```
const colors = [
  { hex: "#f44336", rgb: "244,67,54" },
  { hex: "#2196f3", rgb: "33,150,243" },
  { hex: "#4caf50", rgb: "76,175,80" },
  { hex: "#ffeb3b", rgb: "255,235,59" },
];

const hexColors = [];
const rgbColors = [];

for (const {hex, rgb} of colors) {
  hexColors.push(color.hex);
  rgbColors.push(color.rgb);
}
```

Второй способ:

```
const colors = [
  { hex: "#f44336", rgb: "244,67,54" },
  { hex: "#2196f3", rgb: "33,150,243" },
  { hex: "#4caf50", rgb: "76,175,80" },
  { hex: "#ffeb3b", rgb: "255,235,59" },
];

const hexColors = [];
const rgbColors = [];

for (const color of colors) {
  const { hex, rgb } = color;
  hexColors.push(color.hex);
  rgbColors.push(color.rgb);
}
```

Пишет, что в цикле 'for...of' не используется деструктуризация объекта.
Не могу понять, что от меня хотят эти автопроверки. Вроде все правильно делаю, как в конспекте разными вариантами.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: быть может, хотят, чтобы вы записали цикл в виде  `for (const {hex, rgb} of colors)` без отдельной переменной color

Comment: Писал не помогло. На скрине видно.

Comment: потому что ты продолжаешь пытаться использовать переменную, которой больше нет

Comment: Дошло!! Спасибо:) Самоучение тяжело дается:)

Comment: А как выбирать лучший ответ? У меня на одном вопросе есть галочка, на некоторых нет...

Comment: здесь нет ответов, которые можно выбрать, только комментарии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом способе задача выполняется

```
for (const {hex, rgb} of colors) { // деструктуризация объекта
```

однако в теле цикла

```
hexColors.push(color.hex);
rgbColors.push(color.rgb);
```

используется необъявленная переменная `color`.

Вместо этого нужно было напрямую использовать переменные `hex` и `rgb`

```
hexColors.push(hex);
rgbColors.push(rgb);
```